# How to add actions in Windows 10 Toast content notifications with Java

Tags: java, windows, notifications, toast

I'd like to customize a notification message in Windows 10 by adding two buttons in order to trigger two different actions. [Microsoft toast content tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=builder-syntax) does exactly what I want, but the examples are in C# (which I've never used) and XML which I'm a bit familiar with. Is there a way to achieve the same result in pure java? Or alternatively how can i combine java and xml?

Here is an example of what I want, directly taken from the previously referenced tutorial.
[image: Example of Windows notification with actions]

At the moment I have managed to create a simple notification icon but as you can see from the output the are no actions.

```
 public static void notify() throws AWTException{

    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("");
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    trayIcon.setToolTip("Demo");
    tray.add(trayIcon);

    trayIcon.displayMessage("Hello, World", "notification demo", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
}
```

[image: my notification demo without actions]

Comment: I wrote other functions of the app: i didn't try nothing because i don't know any api or class to do this. Maybe i wasn't clear (i'm going to update the question): i'm not asking the code but suggestions about which api/ java class use to make this tipe of notifications

Comment: The UWP API is in [Windows.UI.Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications).  Look at the "Toast" classes.  I have no idea how to invoke this API from Java.